# New console window when developing in the repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, cider

If I'm developing, let's say, a console text editor, how could I call a **new console frame from the lein repl?** (or any repl)

If it's called `(main "file.txt")` from the repl it would be 'popped' a new console window with the the file.txt content where I could edit.

Comment: See this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037093/how-to-debug-a-console-app-from-the-repl) with a similar problem.