# How to debug a console app from the REPL?

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, cider

It's really confortable to use emacs+cider for the daily development. All the stuff I've configured in my text editor makes it ideal for the task.

The current project that I'm working on my spare time is a **text editor**. *I've already implmented one in C++ and I used `gdb` to debug*, from emacs. To run it, I entered `set new-console on` and `run` in the `gdb` buffer. This would **pop a new console that would handle all the I/O**.

Now I'm trying to reimplement it in Clojure. By far, one of my biggest concerns is debugging. I think it wouldn't be bad something similar to what I used with `gdb`.

For **reading the keyboard without buffering**, I'm using `JLine`. This means `read-line` won't provide the desired result.

What is a **reasonable way to debug this kind of app** (with **lots of I/O from the console**)?

**How to do so from emacs/cider** preferently?

I'm using lein, if this matters.

---

*P.S.*: Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961962/new-console-window-when-developing-in-the-repl) I made, with a more broad "intend". I think it's worth seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CIDER comes with an excellent [debugger](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/doc/debugging.md) nowadays. See also this [screenshot](https://twitter.com/borkdude/status/798894584059351040).

The easiest thing for you will probably be to create a lein/boot build profile which includes nREPL and CIDER as dependencies and make use of an [embedded CIDER instance](http://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation#using-embedded-nrepl-server). This will let you run your app "standalone" from a terminal where you'll be able to get unbuffered keyboard I/O, and you can connect via `M-x cider-connect` to the embedded nREPL+CIDER instance to take full advantage of the debugger and code loading as you normally would.

Comment: Yep, I use it almost every day. The problem here is handle the I/O. For this kind of console app, `read-line` is not enough. The keys must be read unbuffered. I'm currently using `JLine` for this purpose. I'll add this details to the question. But thank you for the answer!

Comment: I'll work this out. If it work, I'll update the answer. Thank you btw!